# how pdo_sqlsrv driver convert float type to string?

Tags: php, sql-server

I set some  table's column type to float and length to 53, set it's value is 38.8,
when i use sqlsrv driver  for a query, it's ok ,  it's show value is 38.8.
But,when i use pdo_sqlsrv driver for a query ,it's show value is 38.799999999999997,
it's why?

Comment: All Floats (in a database or in code) don't store exact decimal values. See this answer I wrote before - same thing applies. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12291065/1450077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decimal number 38.8 is [periodic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) when converted to binary:

```
100110.1100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
       ^^^^
       Repeats forever
```

Thus it cannot be stored exactly in a computer if you chose a regular numeric format (which always have fixed storage sizes).

It doesn't really matter: since you've established you only want 8 decimals, you should get the correct value when discarding the rest:

```
ini_set('precision', 30);
var_dump( 38.8, number_format(38.8, 8) );
```

```
float(38.7999999999999971578290569596)
string(11) "38.80000000"
```

However, if 8<sup>th</sup> decimal is actually important for you, you should switch the column type to `DECIMAL`, which stores numbers internally as strings, thus keeps the exact decimal representation.